# Recreating frequency heatmap in R

Tags: r

I need some help to recreate the plot below with my own data. This plot shows individuals ranked according to different standards and cut into deciles. Then for each pair of deciles the number of individuals is counted.

For example, the first cell = 87. There were 87 individuals that were ranked in the bottom decile (0-10) for both ranking standards.

[image: heatmap-weigel]

The interpretation is not the most important, but how to create it in R is. I know I should start learning `ggplot2` but at the moment I don't have time to learn it.

So, I tried to recreate it using `pairs` on a simple randomly created dataset:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(3546)
y <- rep(1:5, 5)
x <- rep(1:5, rep(5,5))
z <- sample.int(100, 25)
dt <- data.table(x = x, y = y, z = z)
dt <- dcast.data.table(dt, y~x, value.var = "z")[,y := NULL]
```

This was the start of my code, but I quickly realized that I couldn't figure out how to access the index of which panel is being drawn. The whole columns are being inserted into the `panel` functions. While, in fact I only need the element corresponding to which panel is being drawn.

```
pairs(dt, gap = 0L, labels = NULL, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", 
      panel = function(x, y, ...){
        usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
        count <- x[1L]
        par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
        text(0.5, 0.5, count, font = 2, cex = 2)
      })
```

Any suggestions? A `ggplot` answer is welcome.

**[SOLUTION]**

Solution with `r-base`, thanks to A. Webb, taking advantage of vectorization.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(3546)
y <- rep(1:5, 5)
x <- rep(1:5, rep(5,5))
z <- sample.int(100, 25)
color <- c("darkgreen", "green", "yellow", "red", "darkred")
dt <- data.table(x = x, y = y, z = z)
dt[,bg := color[abs(x - y) + 1L]]
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE) 
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0 , 0), oma = c(0, 3, 3, 0))
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(0, max(dt$x)), ylim = c(max(dt$y), 0))
with(dt, rect(x-1, y-1, x, y, col = bg))
with(dt, text(x-0.5, y-0.5, z, font = 2, cex = 2))
par(op)
```

[image: final_solution]

Comment: The example plot does not appear to be a heatmap as the colors are not indicative of values but rather their position relative to the diagonal. What do you actually want?

Comment: You are right its not strictly a heatmap. What should I call it? Frequency matrix plot, or something? I want what I explain in the post. The frequency of the individuals that are in both the x and y decile. Does that make sense?

Comment: `heatmap(as.matrix(dt))`

Comment: @hrbrmstr, thanks for the edits. Just tried that. Not exactly what I am looking for. It reorders it. I want to strictly have 1 to 5 order on both axis. But I will experiment with it. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Webb, I called it a heatmap because the colors indicate how far the individuals deviate from the green diagonal. Ideally everything should be ranked similarly regardless of the ranking technique - all on the green line.

Comment: With the approach in the edit, just call `plot.window(xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1))` after `plot.new()`. Then `rect(0, 0, 1, 1, lty = 1, col = bg_col)` should work fine.

Comment: @A.Webb, yeah I just figured out where I got my thinking wrong. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: @tstev My approach to the base R solution edited into my answer below.

Comment: @A.Webb Really nice! I will adapt my working solution to make advantage of vectorization. I really should be using `with` more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your sample `dt` as the starting point, we'll need to do some preprocessing.

```
    1  2  3  4   5
1: 28 43 45 16 100
2: 60 24 21 61  14
3: 54 49 17 42  29
4: 75 80 76 27  88
5: 56 39 34 53  19
```

I'm not very adept with data.table or Hadley's toolchain yet, so I'll do the prerequisite data wrangling in base R.

```
X<-cbind(arrayInd(1:(nrow(dt)*ncol(dt)),.dim=dim(dt)),c(as.matrix(dt)))
X<-setNames(as.data.frame(X),c("row","col","val"))
X<-transform(X,fill=factor(abs(row-col)))
```

This gives a long format with columns indicating the row number, column number, and a factor level to indicating the shading.

Basic `geom_tile` plot in `ggplot2`

```
ggplot(X,aes(x=col,y=row)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=fill)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral") +
  geom_text(aes(label=val)) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image: tile]

With just base drawing materials, take advantage of the vectorization of `rect` and `text`

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,max(X$col)),ylim=c(max(X$row),0),asp=1)
with(X,rect(col-1,row-1,col,row,col=rainbow(5)[fill]))
with(X,text(col-0.5,row-0.5,val,font=2,cex=2))
```

[image]

Comment: that looks really good! Cheers! I also just managed to get this far another way - but I don't understand why it works. I am adding it just now. It also takes your approach.